# Laravel replace validation value not showing in validated() array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

In my blade form, I have an input field that asks for a hour value, lets say `input_stage_hour`

I am trying to convert this to minutes AFTER validation, but BEFORE it hits my controller ... In my form request im using the `passedValidation` method to convert hours to minutes, then in my controller i am filling my model using `$request->validated()`

The problem is, it is passing through the original value and not the converted value.

My cut down form request is below;

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'input_stage_hour' => ['required', 'numeric', 'integer'],
    ];
}

protected function passedValidation()
{
    $this->replace([
        'input_stage_hour' => intval($this->input_stage_hour) * 60,
    ]);
}
```

If I pass a value like `2` into the `input_stage_hour` and then `dd($request->validated())` in my controller, it still shows the value 2 instead of `120`

Comment: if you want modified data then use $request->all().$request->validated() Get the validated data from the request .

Comment: I would not recommend modifying the input inside a `FormRequest` as you are obfuscating code. A `FormRequest` responsibility is to Validate, not transform data. You can use a Middleware or any other layer you want, but it would be BEFORE it hits the `FormRequest`. Why do you want to validate the value and then transform it and serve that to the controller ? Let the controller handle that transformation, as it should be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data that comes from that `validated` method on the FormRequest is coming from the Validator not the FormRequest itself. So if you really wanted to do this with the FormRequest and be able to call that `validated` method you would have to adjust the data the Validator is holding or adjust the `validated` method.

Example attempting to adjust the data the Validator is holding:

```
protected function passedValidation()
{
    $data = $this->validator->getData();

    $this->validator->setData(
        ['input_stage_hour' => $data['input_stage_hour'] * 60] + $data
    );
}
```

If you wanted to override the `validated` method:

```
public function validated()
{
    $data = parent::validated();

    return ['input_stage_hour' => $data['input_stage_hour'] * 60] + $data;
}
```

Comment: From laravel 9.x, the `validated` method must need two parameters `$key` and `$default` to be passed due to the method signature of the parent class.