# how to add data to validated request input bag

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need to add custom data to the request input array from my customRequest class

I tried this way

```
request()->request->add(['cool' => request()->get('var1').request()->get('var2')]);
```

It's do the trick with `request()->all()` but when I returned `$request->validated()` it's not exist.

**how can I do it?**

Comment: it is the Validator that the `validated` call gets the data from, not the Request itself, so you would need to `setData` on the Validator itself or override the `validated` method on your Request ... Example of doing this from inside the FormRequest itself https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70320201/laravel-replace-validation-value-not-showing-in-validated-array/70320692#70320692

Comment: and a side note, the method to retrieve input from the Request in Laravel is `input`

Comment: I used this `public function validated(){return $this->all();}` but the request content var don't changed.

Comment: if you want to add things to the request, you would want to use the `merge` method usually ... `$request->merge([....])` ... you are dealing with 2 different requests, `request()` is returning the Request instance that is going through the application, `$request` is your FormRequest ... they are different objects (making changes to one of them doesn't change the other one)

Comment: actually i need to add the data into Illuminate\Validation\Validator
data

Comment: yes that is in the FormRequest ... but stop using `request()`, just deal with your FormRequest instance `$request`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$request->validated()` is returning only validated data (data in the request validator class).

After validating the data you can add additional data in the request using

```
$request->merge(['cool' => request()->get('var1')]);
```

Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#merging-additional-input

Comment: that won't end up in the data returned from `validated`; assuming that is the FormRequest you are calling `merge` on

Answer (score 1):

I have done this way

```
protected function passedValidation()
{
    $bar = 'test';
    $validated = $this->validated();
    $validated['foo']   = $bar;

    $this->merge([
        'mergedValidated'   =>  $validated
    ]);

}
```

Then in Controller I did this

```
$request->mergedValidated
```

Answer (score 1):

You add data to the validated request input bag by either adding it to the request before validation and then validating it OR adding it to the array produced by `$request->validated();`. Since you want it in the result of `$request->validated();` then:

in your form request:

```
public function rules(): array
{   
   return [
        //...other validation rules,
        'cool' => ['sometimes'] //or any other rule that you require
   ];
}

protected function prepareForValidation(): void
{ 
   $this->merge(['cool' => request()->get('var1').request()->get('var2')]);
}
```

in your controller

```
//$validated array will have the 'cool' key
 $validated = $request->validated();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is what I did, and it worked for me.
You can store the validated data in a variable as shown below.

```
$validated_data = $request->validated();
```

And then make your changes on the `$validated_data` variable as shown below.

```
$validated_data['cool'] = $request->input('var1').$request->input('var2');
```

This should add the extra data to the validated data.

Answer (score -1):

You can merge with new array

```
array_merge(request()->all(), ['cool' =>  request()->get('var1').request()->get('var2')]);
```